# a GUI exe file will not open through task scheduler, but ok when running manually through Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

Good day:
I am new to powershell. I have a very simple task that I want to run through task scheduler everyday. I have a simple powershell script :
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Concilio\Concilio.exe"  .
which should open this GUI application Concilio.exe. I works ok when I run it manually(right click the file, and run with Powershell). It would open up the GUI(Concilio.exe) file. In The actions Tab, I selected to Start a program.

Under Program/script I selected the Powershell Path: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
Under Add arguments, I had :
C:\Users\rgong\Downloads\test.ps1

I then tried to see if there is something wrong with my commands, I comment out my original Start-Process script, changed it to remove a text file. it then will work under task scheduler. I searched online for quite a while, I have seen other people had similar issues where their script would work if runs manually but not working through task scheduler, but my issue is a bit different from theirs. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Processes opened through Task Scheduler have no User Interface. You won't be able to see a GUI-based application. Concilio.exe will probably fail to start, or run in the background, depending on how it handles the lack of UI.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back Rich. Do you know is there any other options that I could use?

Comment: You could put a shortcut to the application in your startup folder to run every time you login. What does it do, and why do you want it to run at a scheduled time?

Comment: Hi Rich, it was an ERP application on Middleware. It was a temp fix so insure data in sync. I would like to have it running without me logging into the middleware cause we have hundreds of middleware so it is impossible for me to log in every day for every machine.